# Create a new page in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writing a plugin that lets people add course information online. 'Courses' is a custom post type. I've already made the admin menu to add the course information to the database (in the post meta table).

Now I need to bring it out onto the front end. Ideally I'd like to make a new template page (single-courses.php) so I can fully customise the page. I've not found anything that fits the bill online yet, is there an easy way of generating this through the plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it, not perfect but it works...

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template');

function my_template(){
global $post;
if( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'courses'){
include(ABSPATH. 'wp-content/plugins/courses/single-course.php');
}
```

And the file the include points to is my new template file in the plugin.

Comment: Use `plugin_dir_path()`. `wp-content` can be moved and renamed.

Comment: With the uncertainty of themes, I think this is generally a challenge. You might look at The Events Calendar which has fairly robust templating for a plugin. They do something similar to this. Also, you might consider filtering `the_content` instead of adding a template. That strikes me as much safer when it comes to cross-theme compatibility.

Comment: Yep I actually did a filter on the_content first, i agree i thought it was safer, but my boss and collegues seemed to think a template would be better so just doing what I'm told! Thanks for the answers, I've kept it as it is redirecting to the new template, I checked out the event calendar, there is some good but quite heavy stuff there! And I'll change the abspath to something more futureproof. Thanks :)